# How to modify `proxies_priv` in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, permissions

I recently received a warning from MySQL that stated:

```
[Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@serverdomain' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
```

I looked in `mysql.proxies_priv` and there is definitely an entry for "serverdomain", however there is no user with "@serverdomain".  Documentation on this is very sparse, [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant-table-structure.html) is all I could find.

How do I remove this entry and how was it ever created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [**link from your question**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant-table-structure.html), look at the table `mysql.proxies_priv`

```
mysql> show create table mysql.proxies_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: proxies_priv
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `proxies_priv` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Proxied_host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Proxied_user` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `With_grant` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Grantor` char(77) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`User`,`Proxied_host`,`Proxied_user`),
  KEY `Grantor` (`Grantor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='User proxy privileges'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Since it is a MyISAM table, you could just truncate the table.

In case you need it back, make a backup of it and truncate it after.

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.proxies_priv RENAME mysql.proxies_priv_backup;
CREATE TABLE mysql.proxies_priv LIKE mysql.proxies_priv_backup;
```

Then, go restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

A far simpler way would be to use the [**REVOKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html) command:

```
REVOKE PROXY ON user
    FROM user [, user] ...
```

Due to the warning, you would have to restart mysql to make sure the warning does not come back.

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how it was created, but the easiest way to remove it is using the following SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM `proxies_priv` 
WHERE `proxies_priv`.`Host` = 'serverdomain' 
      AND `proxies_priv`.`User` = 'root' 
      AND `proxies_priv`.`Proxied_host` = '' 
      AND `proxies_priv`.`Proxied_user` = '';
```